# How to allow non-root users to run certain programs (for example the KDE app store) without root

Tags: permissions, sudo, non-root-user

Put simply, Whenever somebody logs onto the family computer that I manage, I get bugged about updates and "could you install x thing that I saw in the store" and such. How would I enable all users to run flatpak, snap, and plasma-discover without root? All questions about this that I have seen previously seen only cover running one command without root access. [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) does not answer my question as it addresses allowing a user to run a single program without root access.

Comment: program(S) plural

Comment: Then just add the other commands into the list: `myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/executable1,  /path/to/executable2,  /path/to/executable3, ...`

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but could i add a group with all of these commands enabled, rather than adding each permission like 5 times for different people?

Comment: Yes; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168309/117549 for one example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo` for that. You can specify what users are allowed to run commands, what commands can be executed, and whether to ask for a password of not. See the manual for details.

If you don't want to that users have to type `sudo` in front of the commands, create aliases in `/etc/profile` for the commands that will run the commands with `sudo`.

Comment: Could you link me to the manual/ man page?

Comment: You can type `man sudo` at the command prompt, or you can type "man sudo" into Google.If you can't find a man page yourself, you shouldn't run programs as root.

Comment: been linuxing for a while, and nobody, NOBODY, has mentioned man as a command, making me think it was another name for a readme